# ArcGIS: restrict FeatureLayer SQL access based on token

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, sql, mapbox, feature-layer

I am working on a web app using the ArcGIS API for JavaScript that fetches a FeatureLayer from ArcGIS Online. The web app has users with many different permission roles and I want users to **be able to access only specific columns/rows of the FeatureLayer**. For this I [query the FeatureLayer with SQL](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/query-a-feature-layer-sql).

Does anyone know how I could implement a permission-based system?

I was thinking of giving to the user a token **based on its role**, but when the client makes SQL queries to the FeatureLayer, how can I **restrict the SQL queries it can make**?

For example, user with token `X` should be able to access the `color` and `area` column, but not the column `material` and only rows where the column `id` has value `123`.

Creating a own FeatureLayer for every role is cumbersome and not a desirable solution, since we would talk about hundreds of FeatureLayers that need to be created and uploaded each time the dataset changes. Furthermore, we noticed that letting the client load multiple FeatureLayers degrades performance dramatically.

### Update

We switched to Mapbox and create now a own Mapbox account for each user who's data should not be seen by any other user. We split our GeoJSONs with a custom tool we made and upload them on the corresponding Mapbox account. The splitting tool might become open source one day

Comment: This would be better implemented in the web tier (which would make this more of a [so] issue).

Comment: Hi! What you would like to achieve is quite difficult and expensive to implement, and has been a large topic in the ArcGIS Community. We are using [third party software](https://vertigisstudio.com/products/vertigis-studio-access-control) to do that in my organization, but only works on premises. You can try to make a kind of a proxy in your app, which filters the attribute and rows base on the user role, but it is not a easy travel, since a lot of possibilities need to be taken into account.

Comment: Thanks @Katah for the tip! I intend to dedicate 2 months on this, so I may  try to implement a subset of the Web Map Service standard and add the permission role authentication that we need.